# C# me cambia las comillas a codigo ASCII

Tags: c#, mvc, ascii

Estoy haciendo un proyecto c# en MVC , donde intento pasar una variable string que trae comillas simples en su texto, pero al recibirlo me lo cambia a codigo ascii,
he intentado de utilizar replace("& #39;","'"), pero no pasa nada queda con el codigo ascii si o si.

Comment: Me sale asi:

{label:& #39;1401 - CREDITOS COMERCIALES VENCIDOS& #39;, data: [ [1, 77] ], color: & #39;#0088cc& #39; }

y lo quieron así:

{label: '1401 - CREDITOS COMERCIALES VENCIDOS', data: [ [1, 77] ], color: ´#0088cc' }

he intentado:

miString.Replace("& #39;", "'") y no pasa nada queda igual

Comment: Por favor utiliza el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285947/c-me-cambia-las-comillas-a-codigo-ascii-problema#) cuando desees agregar mas detalles a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer uso de este código, creo que es el mismo problema que tienes.

```
string myStringToDecode = "Hello &#39;World&#39;";

string decodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myStringToDecode);
// or
string decodedString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(myStringToDecode);
```

Fuente:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158346/remove-or-convert-39-to

Saludos